# Previous Activity closes when starting new Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio

I have an odd phenomenon.

In my MainActivity I have a button, which starts a new activity.

I used:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

The second activity just has an small `ImageView` and the background is transparent. When the button is clicked, the second activity should overlay the `MainActivity`, which should be seen in the background.

It does work on my phone (API Level 21) but not on my friends one (API Level 19). On my phone everything works as it should. 
On my friends phone the `MainActivity` closes and there is just the ImageView and the background picture of his phone.
How can we prevent that the `MainActivity` gets closed on his phone when starting the second one?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: it might be just a clue but, there is a settings on debug options saying "do not keep activities" etc.  it might be enabled on your buddy's phone.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. Unfortunately it wasn't enabled on my friends phone...

Answer (score 0):

Also, in Android Manifest.xml you can set the lowest version of Android, which may be the problem?

Comment: When we starte the project, the API Level of the app was set for API Level 15. So it should work on my friends phone.